# Using response value in the next request url path in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am stuck in jmeter. 
I want an value extracted from the Response body and use that in the next request url path in jmeter.
I tried using "Regular expressions" but it is not working.
[Response body SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorpp.jpg)

From "Response body SS" i want to extract the locationID value(341735)

[Request URL PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eagKI.jpg)

Use the extracted value in the url path at highlighted section.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns this "Response body SS"
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `locationID`
   - XPath query: `/response/locationID`
   - Match No: `1`

     [image]
3. That's it, the XPath Extractor will get the value and you will be able to use it as `${locationID}` where required

   [image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/)